# Sphinx admonitions not rendering properly

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, myst

I am writing documentation using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) and would like to include admonitions. An example shown is shown here for the [Book](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/) theme: https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/kitchen-sink/paragraph-markup.html#admonitions

However, when including admonitions in my own documentation, they simply render as text:

:::{seealso} See Add a link to your repository for more information.
:::

Rather than a styled box:

[image]

What could be going wrong? I have enabled the `myst_parser` extension. I tried with other themes, which have slightly different admonition syntax, but am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Don't use colons (`:`) for fences. Use backticks.

````
```{seealso}
See Add a link to your repository for more information.
```
````

2. [Enable colons in code fences](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#code-fences-using-colons).

> By adding "colon_fence" to `myst_enable_extensions` (in the sphinx `conf.py` configuration file), you can also use `:::` delimiters to denote code fences, instead of ```.